# Error Code 1064 using MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE

Tags: mysql-workbench, sql-insert

Receiving the following error code when inserting data into the `Sales_Rep` table.

```
INSERT INTO Sales_Rep VALUES (‘03’, ’Jones’, ’Mary’, ’123 Main’, ’Grant’, ’MI’, ’49219’, 2150.00, .05)
```

Error:

> Error Code:1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Main’, ’Grant’, ’MI’, ’49219’, 2150.00, .05)' at line 1 0.000
>   sec

Prior to insert successfully executed the following MySQL commands to create database and tables.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS DBMS;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS DBMS;
USE DBMS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Sales_Rep;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Customer;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Orders;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Part;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Order_Line;
CREATE TABLE Sales_Rep (
Sales_Rep_Number VARCHAR(2) primary key,
Last_Name VARCHAR(15),
First_Name VARCHAR(15),
Street VARCHAR(15),
City VARCHAR(15),
State VARCHAR(2),
Zip_Code VARCHAR(7),
Commission double,
Rate double)
ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Any idea of what formatting changes are needed to insert data into the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the wrong quote characters. There are 3 quote chars which are supported in MySQL:

1. The single quote: `'`, which denotes strings, like in `'a string'`.
2. The double quote: `"`, which denotes strings if ANSI_MODE is off, and identifiers with ANSI_MODE on.
3. The backtick: `(cannot use markup here as the backtick is used in Markdown as code delimiter). The backtick denotes an identifier.

Quoted identifiers can include special chars, which are usually not allowed, including whitespaces.

You used the forward tick in your query `´` where you probably meant to have strings:

```
INSERT INTO Sales_Rep VALUES ('03', 'Jones', 'Mary', '123 Main', 'Grant', 'MI', '49219', 2150.00, .05);
```

Be careful when you copy queries from certain applications, like word processors, which automatically convert simple quote chars into typographic quote chars.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  Figured it was the quote identifier but wasn't sure how it was happening.  Above was copied over from Word (.doc) file.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the MySQL Community Server - GPL version 8.0.30 started using docker compose using this yaml file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: blablabla
            MYSQL_USER: blablabla
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: blablabla
        ports:
            - '3306:3306'
        volumes:
            - <$HOME_DIRECTORY>/Documents/dev/rdbms/mysql_server_data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
    blablabla:
        driver: local
```

and this error code 1064 was solved when I changed the double quotes by single quotes in the values columns of the insert into  statement.